# Configuring MDB in Openejb 3.1.4 and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, message-driven-bean, openejb, mq

I am using Tomcat & OpenEJB 3.1.4.Working with Message Driven Bean(EJB 2.0 - MDB) to recieve messages from MQ.What all configuration or Setup I need to do with OpenEJB-Tomcat to recieve messages via MDB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the JMS api, to configure the topic/queue to listen to,
you could add an entry in the openejb.xml as shown in [topic/queue section here](http://openejb.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html)

The configuration syntax is like  key=value (property-file like syntax) inside an xml file.

Comment: I'm not sure, more configurations might be required. Meant the answer as a pointer..